# How to store the total withdrawal amount for each category object?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a `Category` class and there is a ledger attribute for each instance of this class. This ledger attribute is actually a list of dictionaries which contain the withdrawal and deposit amounts and descriptions in the form `{"amount" : amount, "description" : description}`. Now, I want to define a function `create_spend_chart` which will take a list of objects as the parameter, and will find the total amount of withdrawals. I have been able to do this successfully:

```py
    def create_spend_chart(categories):
        total_withdrawn = 0
        for i in categories:
            for p in i.ledger:
                if p["amount"] < 0:
                    total_withdrawn += -p["amount"]
```

But the problem I'm facing here is, I can't seem to store the total withdrawal amount for **each** category object separately. How can I do this?

My code-base might help you ins answering the question:

```py
    class Category:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.ledger = list()
    
        def get_balance(self):
            total_balance = 0
            for i in self.ledger:
                total_balance += i["amount"]
            return total_balance
    
        def check_funds(self, amount):
            if self.get_balance() >= amount:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        
        def deposit(self, amount, description = "Deposit"):
            form = {"amount" : int(amount), "description" : description}
            self.ledger.append(form)
        
        def withdraw(self, amount, description = "Withdrawal"):
            if description == None:
                description = "Withdrawal"
    
            form = {"amount" : -int(amount), "description" : description}
            if self.check_funds(amount):
                self.ledger.append(form)
                return True
            else:
                return False
        
        def transfer(self, amount, category_object):
            form1 = {"amount" : -int(amount), "description" :  f"Transfer to {category_object.name}"}
            form2 = {"amount" : int(amount), "description" :  f"Transfer from {self.name}"}
            
            if self.check_funds(amount):
                self.ledger.append(form1)
                category_object.ledger.append(form2)
                return True
            else:
                return False
        def __repr__(self):
            Ledger = ""
            for i in self.ledger:
                if len(i["description"]) > 23:
                    des = i["description"][:23]
                else:
                    des = i["description"]
                Ledger += des.ljust(23) + str(round(i["amount"], 2)).rjust(7) + "\n"
            Ledger = Ledger + "Total: " + str(round(self.get_balance(), 2))
            receipt = f"{self.name}".center(30, "*") + "\n" + Ledger
            return receipt
    
    def create_spend_chart(categories):
        total_withdrawn = 0
        withdrawals = list()
        for i in categories:
            for p in i.ledger:
                if p["amount"] < 0:
                    total_withdrawn += -p["amount"]
```

**PS**: This function is not a method, it is defined outside of the class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make aggregations such as that easy as pie.

```
import collections

# ...

withdrawn_per_category = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i in categories:
    for p in i.ledger:
        if p["amount"] < 0:
            withdrawn_per_category[i.name] += -p["amount"]
```

(I've opted to use `int` as the default data type, but it doesn't truly matter here, so long as it's a conversible numeric type.)

### Without `collections`

If for some reason you don't want to use the handy, built-in `collections` module, you can emulate the same behavior yourself with a regular dict:

```
withdrawn_per_category = {}
for i in categories:
    for p in i.ledger:
        if p["amount"] < 0:
            withdrawn_per_category[i.name] = withdrawn_per_category.get(i.name, 0) - p["amount"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Is there any way that I could be able to store these values  (withdrawals per category) in a list instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Of course. The easiest way would be to do something like `withdrawals_per_category_list = list(withdrawn_per_category.items())` after you've done that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've run into a problem. When I now run the program, it gives an error ```NameError: name 'collections' is not defined```. What do I do about this?

Comment: Add `import collections`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without importing any external modules?

Comment: Yes, there is, but why bother? `collections` is a built-in module, it's available with every Python. (Nevertheless, I added the collections-less dict version.)

Comment: Thaaaaaaaanks!!