# How to store the total withdrawn amount for each category obejct?

Tags: python

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64445777/8656272) post because that post was answered by importing an external module while I request in this post to try to answer this question without importing any.

I have a `Category` class and there is a ledger attribute for each instance of this class. This ledger attribute is actually a list of dictionaries which contain the withdrawal and deposit amounts and descriptions in the form

```
{"amount" : amount, "description" : description}
```

Now, I want to define a function `create_spend_chart` which will take a list of objects as the parameter, and will find the total amount of withdrawals. I have been able to do this successfully:

```
def create_spend_chart(categories):
    total_withdrawn = 0
    for i in categories:
        for p in i.ledger:
            if p["amount"] < 0:
                total_withdrawn += -p["amount"]
```

This function is not a method, it is defined outside of the class declaration.

But the problem I'm facing here is, I can't seem to store the total withdrawal amount for **each** category object separately. How can I do this?

My code:

```
class Category:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.ledger = list()

    def get_balance(self):
        total_balance = 0
        for i in self.ledger:
            total_balance += i["amount"]
        return total_balance

    def check_funds(self, amount):
        if self.get_balance() >= amount:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def deposit(self, amount, description = "Deposit"):
        form = {"amount" : int(amount), "description" : description}
        self.ledger.append(form)
    
    def withdraw(self, amount, description = "Withdrawal"):
        if description == None:
            description = "Withdrawal"

        form = {"amount" : -int(amount), "description" : description}
        if self.check_funds(amount):
            self.ledger.append(form)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def transfer(self, amount, category_object):
        form1 = {"amount" : -int(amount), "description" :  f"Transfer to {category_object.name}"}
        form2 = {"amount" : int(amount), "description" :  f"Transfer from {self.name}"}
        
        if self.check_funds(amount):
            self.ledger.append(form1)
            category_object.ledger.append(form2)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __repr__(self):
        Ledger = ""
        for i in self.ledger:
            if len(i["description"]) > 23:
                des = i["description"][:23]
            else:
                des = i["description"]
            Ledger += des.ljust(23) + str(round(i["amount"], 2)).rjust(7) + "\n"
        Ledger = Ledger + "Total: " + str(round(self.get_balance(), 2))
        receipt = f"{self.name}".center(30, "*") + "\n" + Ledger
        return receipt

def create_spend_chart(categories):
    total_withdrawn = 0
    withdrawals = list()
    for i in categories:
        for p in i.ledger:
            if p["amount"] < 0:
                total_withdrawn += -p["amount"]
```

Comment: What does your ```categories```(argument for create_spend_chart) look like as an input?

Comment: the argument "categories" is a  python list of instances of the class Category

Comment: may I ask why you're trying to avoid `collections`? It's a part of the standard library, you don't have to install anything external to use it.

Comment: @Chase I'm just very curious as to how would one solve this problem if one didn't have the module 'collections'

Comment: By implementing the function in `collections`. Which is open source btw, so you can check that out if you're curious. There is absolutely no reason to reinvent the wheel in python though, if a module exists in the standard library - it's there for you to use.